# Does a process that have the root user always have all of the capabilities available in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

In Linux, a process that have a non-root user can have some capabilities assigned to it to increase its privileges.

And a process that have the root user have all of the capabilities available, but can such a process have some of its capabilities removed (either manually or automatically in certain situations)?

Comment: This question is more suited for "https://unix.stackexchange.com/".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, because root is allowed to access everything - per os design.

That's the reason why modern Linux distributions often hides the root user and work with the sudo approach instead.